# spring-boot-maven-plugin:build-image fails with 400 Bad Request

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven

I am trying to build a docker image for my basic Spring Boot application using the spring-boot-maven-plugin:build-image goal.

It fails with the below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.0-M2:build-image (default-cli) on project spring-docker: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.0-M2:build-image failed: **Docker API call to 'localhost/v1.24/containers/eaaba1e2a727547ae53df3c1f7c4420ba821914b4392ea12ff47326ee03eeaa5/start' failed with status code 400 "Bad Request"** -> [Help 1]
```

I have tried with both **Spring Boot 2.3.3.RELEASE** as well as **2.4.0-M2** and I get the same error.

I have Docker Desktop running on a Windows 10 machine.

`$ docker version`

```
**Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.12
 API version:       1.40**
 Go version:        go1.13.10
 Git commit:        48a66213fe
 Built:             Mon Jun 22 15:43:18 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

**Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.12
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)**
  Go version:       go1.13.10
  Git commit:       48a66213fe
  Built:            Mon Jun 22 15:49:27 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Full stack trace:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.0-M2:build-image (default-cli) on project spring-docker: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.0-M2:build-image failed: Docker API call to 'localhost/v1.24/containers/cbdb316cb8cb0fbdf641bc7347f56701429d7a887fb240768e8710d36ca5f836/start' failed with status code 400 "Bad Request" -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.0-M2:build-image (default-cli) on project spring-docker: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.0-M2:build-image failed: Docker API call to 'localhost/v1.24/containers/cbdb316cb8cb0fbdf641bc7347f56701429d7a887fb240768e8710d36ca5f836/start' failed with status code 400 "Bad Request"
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.0-M2:build-image failed: Docker API call to 'localhost/v1.24/containers/cbdb316cb8cb0fbdf641bc7347f56701429d7a887fb240768e8710d36ca5f836/start' failed with status code 400 "Bad Request"
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.transport.DockerEngineException: Docker API call to 'localhost/v1.24/containers/cbdb316cb8cb0fbdf641bc7347f56701429d7a887fb240768e8710d36ca5f836/start' failed with status code 400 "Bad Request"
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.transport.HttpClientTransport.execute (HttpClientTransport.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.transport.HttpClientTransport.post (HttpClientTransport.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.DockerApi$ContainerApi.start (DockerApi.java:264)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.Lifecycle.run (Lifecycle.java:148)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.Lifecycle.execute (Lifecycle.java:113)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.Builder.executeLifecycle (Builder.java:133)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.Builder.build (Builder.java:72)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.BuildImageMojo.buildImage (BuildImageMojo.java:152)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.BuildImageMojo.execute (BuildImageMojo.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

Comment: I'm also having the same exact issue, also on a Win10 Docker installation. However, I can eliminate some things as solutions that I have so far tried myself and haven't worked (mostly trying to generate the image in other environments).

The project that produces this error for me throws the same error when trying to build the image with the docker plugin (as opposed to the springboot one) and it's showing the same problem running on Ubuntu 18 and a Mac Catalina, all running on the Docker engine 19.03 If it helps at all, the problem started today on a project that ran ok just yesterday :/

Comment: I'd suggest tagging it with the "docker" tag also.

Comment: Having the same issue as well, just started today

Comment: I have too this problem, it is started today, `19.08.2020 `. I am trying build image on ubuntu and in git ci pipline. All projects yesterday working, but today have error

Comment: today - it`s working

Comment: It started working today without any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Doing

docker volume prune

was resolved my issue.

Comment: dangerous command, use with caution ! also, doesn't resolve the issue for me.