# spring-boot:build-image with SpringBoot Version 2.3.3.RELEASE - spring-boot-maven-plugin:build-image fails with 400 Bad Request

Tags: spring-boot, docker, buildpack

On `macOS Big Sur` and also on `AzureDevOps` pipeline I am getting **failed: Docker API call to** with **./mvnw spring-boot:build-image -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName=springio/gs-spring-boot-docker***

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:build-image
> (default-cli) on project gs-spring-boot-docker: Execution default-cli
> of goal
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:build-image
> failed: Docker API call to
> 'localhost/v1.24/containers/6cf0cbedfbb65cb5a9826c7fbef5e32266e51dd50e01a5afce99701b1d3f5e2a/start'
> failed with status code 400 "Bad Request" -> [Help

Reproduce :

`git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot-docker.git unzip demo.zip cd demo ./mvnw spring-boot:build-image -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName=springio/gs-spring-boot-docker`

Machine:

`uname -a Darwin MacBookPro 20.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.0.0: Thu Jul 30 22:49:28 PDT 2020; root:xnu-7195.0.0.141.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`

Docker Version:

`docker -v Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe`

Comment: Seems to be the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492180/spring-boot-maven-pluginbuild-image-fails-with-400-bad-request